# Kensington SD I/O Read Error, not recognised on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ubuntu, fdisk, fsck, sd-card, dmesg

I have two Kensington SD cards that will not be recognised on my ubuntu 19.04 OS. They are definitely working though, when I plug them into my windows 10 computer they register.

I also have an old ScanDisk SD that does register on both the windows and linux OS'. I plugged the Kensington SD cards into the internal SD card reader fresh from the package and they never registered. I then plugged them into my Nikon camera took some photos and plugged them back into my laptop.

Under my dev directory there is only mmcblk0 not the usual mmcblk0p1. When I run gparted it tries to find the partition I get the error `Input/output error during read on /dev/mmcblk0` about 10-15 times. Eventually resulting in the gparted tool displaying `unallocated`.

Using the fdisk command doesnt show the presence of the /dev/mmcblk0. 
I have tried using `dd` to writes zeros over the whole disk but to no avail.

I also have tried formatting the sd cards on multiple different machines. On my the Nikon, on Windows, and Linux but that hasnt changed anything.

I tried running `fsck.fat /dev/mmcblk0` which output.

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Read 512 bytes at 0:Input/output error
```

I run the `dmesg` command which results in

```
[ 1667.699436] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 0007
[ 1667.700145] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD32G 28.9 GiB 
[ 1667.757553] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1667.813542] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1667.869531] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1667.925599] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1667.981556] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1668.037584] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1668.093597] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1668.257546] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1668.313619] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 1668.315912] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 flags 0
[ 1668.315922] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
```

This output basically outputs over and over. When the ScanDisk is plugged in it gives the message.

```
[ 1328.140396] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address e624
[ 1328.142666] mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SS32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 1328.162378]  mmcblk0: p1
```

Answer (score 0):

cant yet comment, sry

I would suggest to Check

```
lsblk
```

and give the output, in case there are nö data, you can use

wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0

for wiping the  complete ssd and recreate it with

```
fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

and c for create p for primär and then w, q as i remeber

However, as i See you try to fsck a device not the partion

```
 fsck.fat /dev/mmcblk0
 is wrong
```

because

```
 [ 1328.162378]  mmcblk0: p1
```

announces that mmcblk0 has partion p1 as ususally the block am should be mmcblk0p1

sofar that means try

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
```

and check the logs

Comment: lsblk returns 

     `mmcblk0 179:0    0  28.9G  0 disk `

unfortunately the `[ 1328.162378]  mmcblk0: p1` read out is for a SD that does mount and works fine, not the Kensington brand SDs that seems to have problems.

Comment: just put lsblk and give the complete output